# How do I specify a Variable as an Integer in BASIC?

Tags: variables, integer, basic

So I'm writing a very basic 'Game' Program, just really started coding today, and am running into a problem. The tutorial I'm following, at http://home.cmit.net/rwolbeck/programmingtutorial/index.htm suggests that I do not need to specify that a variable is an integer variable, but whether I do or don't, BlitzMax stops compiling midway with an error message of "Compile Error: Unable to convert 'String' to 'Int'"

```
name$ = Input("What is your name? ")
Print "Hello " + name$
answer = Input("What is 2 and 2? ")

If name$ = "Kyle"
    Print "Kyle is always right."
    WaitKey()
    End
EndIf

If answer = 4
    Print "No, 2 and 2 is 22."
Else
    Print "No, 2 and 2 is 4."
EndIf

WaitKey()
End
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong, and how to fix it?

P.S. Just joined this site today but I did do multiple searches and didn't find anything answering this specific question/problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem line:

```
answer = Input("What is 2 and 2? ")
```

Your lack of a "$" on your "answer" variable tells it that it's an integer (in classic Dartmouth BASIC that would be a floating point, with "%" designating an integer).  The INPUT function returns a string, which can't be stuffed into a number.   Use the VAL function to do the type conversion, i.e.

```
answer = Val(Input("What is 2 and 2? "))
```